# Find the domain for a function with 2 or more variables.

Tags: functions

I have the following function:

```
f(x,y)=4x+y/(2x-5y).
```

For this function, I have to find the domain of the function, and to represent it graphically.

Comment: The expression is defined if and only if $2x\ne 5y$

Comment: Please include your attempts as well as some context. Read the community guidelines if you are unsure about how to ask a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x,y):=\dfrac{4x+y}{2x-5y}$, we only have to be sure that the term $2x-5y$ is not equal to zero.
So $5y\ne 2x \iff y\ne\dfrac{2}{5}x\implies \text {dom}(f)=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:y\ne\dfrac{2}{5}x\}$.
The domain is represented by the set $\mathbb R^2$ \ $r$, where $r\equiv y=\dfrac{2}{5}x$.